# Javascript add linebreak, \n not working

Tags: javascript, line-breaks

I want to add a linebreak in Javascript, but \n is not working and nothing else I found so far is not working (like `<br>` or `\n`). Also, because of the programming I cannot use .appendChild.

```
for (i=getchilds();i<number;i++){
     container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\n" + "Pers. " + (i+1) + " \u00a0"));
     var input = document.createElement("input");
     input.type = "number";
     container.appendChild(input);
}
```

Comment: Can you add code for `getchilds()`?

Comment: Use ```<br />``` instead of ```\n``` if you insert it to html page.

Comment: Your code works, but you need to use something that respects whitespace like `pre`: https://jsfiddle.net/kh38j9xc/ Or `white-space: pre` in a selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be confusing whitespace with the *representation* of whitespace. In your case you're appending characters that represent white-space to a string that you intend to be displayed as a line-break. I assume you're then appending it to an element whose style is not set to display it as white-space.

There are four basic ways to fix this:

1. Use an [ordered list](https://jsfiddle.net/kh38j9xc/5/). If you can, do this, since it will be both structural and semantic. Notice the link shows how to control the list-item text (controlling the start number is more challenging).
2. If the `container`-referenced element accommodates this, add `white-space: pre` to it's style. This will cause your line-breaks to come into view. It's best to do this with [CSS](https://jsfiddle.net/kh38j9xc/4/), but you can do it with [Javascript](https://jsfiddle.net/kh38j9xc/1/) too.
3. Replace the `\n` with a `<br>`. Denys Séguret has an example of this.
4. Use a `pre` tag for the `container`-referenced element. `<pre>` automatically respects and displays line-breaks in content. This of course implies your content accommodates using a `pre`-formatted tag.

Comment: Perfect, thanks, I was missing the white-space: pre style in html like you said.

Answer (score 0):

You can't insert `\n` in text node and have them correctly rendered in an element with standard [white-space](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) rendering.

Two solutions here:

#### insert `<br>` elements

```
container.appendChild(document.createElement("BR"));
container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Pers. " + (i+1) + " \u00a0"));
```

#### use `innerText` in SPAN

```
var node = document.createElement("SPAN");
node.innerText = "\n Pers. " + (i+1) + " \u00a0";
container.appendChild(node);
```

The first one is the most relevant in your case, but the fact `innerText` doesn't remove newlines (contrary to `textContent`) is often useful.

Comment: Is there a particular browser the OP's original code does work in? Simply [adding `container.style.whiteSpace = 'pre';`](https://jsfiddle.net/kh38j9xc/1/) would fix the display.

Comment: @JaredFarrish This should be an additional answer (even if I would rarely use whiteSpace pre as it applies to *all* white spaces, not just those specific ones.

Comment: *You can't insert `\n` in text node and have them correctly rendered.* The line breaks can be rendered as the OP intended by changing the parent element's styling.

Comment: @JaredFarrish Stop hammering this, you already said it. Make an answer if you think it's a valid solution (I think it is).

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to insert into a textarea or a set of pre tags.

You might see your code injecting a single space in place of the line breaks in a plain text input of your browser is Firefox chrome or opera.

Comment: Or use [`container.style.whiteSpace = 'pre';`](https://jsfiddle.net/kh38j9xc/1/).

Comment: Yup, that's basically what I said :)